# Trying to be as terse as possible with C#

Tags: c#, nullable

I'm looking for a more terse way of expressing the following test in C# where x is a nullable int

English:
if x has a value AND y > x then do something

C# to make more terse:

```
if(x.HasValue && y > x)
```

Analogously, if I wanted to default a nullable boolean value (x) to false I might write:

```
if(x ?? false)
{
    //x is true
}
else
{
    //x is either null or false
}
```

instead of:

```
if(x.HasValue() && x == true)
```

Many thanks

Comment: The lifted comparison operators are defined as returning false if either operand is null. You don't need to check to see if the operands have values. See section 7.3.7 of the C# 4 specification for details.

Comment: "if(x.HasValue && y > x)" is probably as terse as it should be. At a certain point more simplification isn't practical and in some cases can make code less readable.

Answer (score 11):

`y > x` should be sufficient.

```
0 >= (int?)null // false
0 <= (int?)null // false
```

(OTOH, I have been bitten by this behavior where I thought something would be "large than" null. In these cases, `y > (x ?? 0)` or similar might be useful.)

From Ben Voigt's comment on [Using Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx):

> > When you perform comparisons with nullable types, **if the value of one of the nullable types is null and the other is not, all comparisons evaluate to false except for != (not equal).** It is important not to assume that because a particular comparison returns false, the opposite case returns true.

Happy coding.

Comment: Here's the important part of [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx): "When you perform comparisons with nullable types, if the value of one of the nullable types is null and the other is not, all comparisons evaluate to false except for `!=` (not equal)."

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for the reference. I've update the answer to reflect.

Answer (score 3):

`if(x.HasValue && y > x)` is pretty terse as it is, not to mention clear.  Workarounds would be somewhat contrived.  Consider:

```
if ((x ?? (y + 1)) < y)
```

As pst notes, you don't actually need the `HasValue` call here.  But for clarity's sake it may be a good idea to include it nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

While there may be a way to make the statement more terse, I would steer clear of it.  The usage you show is pretty idiomatic, and makes your intent clear.  Relying on the behavior of nullable inequality operators (as in @pst's answer) could lead to misunderstandings of the code, as well as downplay the fact that the variable is nullable.  I would stick with what you have.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an extension method.

```
public static class IntegerExtensions
{
    public static bool IsLargerThan(this int? number, int numberToCompare)
    {
        return number.HasValue && number > numberToCompare;
    }
}

...

// Usage:

int? val1 = 15;
int val2 = 10;

if (val1.IsLargerThan(val2))
{
    // Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [GetValueOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0.aspx) method?

If x is an `int?`, then your first if statement could be rewritten as  `if (x.GetValueOrDefault() > y)`.  If x is a `bool?`, it can simply be rewritten as `if(x.GetValueOrDefault())`.